# Multitrigger does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, multitrigger

I have a problem with my MultiTrigger and I don't know what is wrong.

This is my MultiTrigger:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Innerborder" Value="#FFFF0000"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Innerborder" Value="#FF295B2E"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
</MultiTrigger>
```

It simply doesn't work and I don't know why.

At another place in my code I have a similar MultiTrigger which works perfectly fine.

I hope you can help me

What I have tried:

Copy&Pasted my other working MultiTrigger (with editing the TargetName)

Answer (score 0):

This can be closed. Found my mistake. It is not related to the Multitrigger. So sorry for bothering you with this question

Comment: You should post your answer.  You may be able to help others.